# Marker position when inframe is in li

Tags: html, css

I know that it is a simple matter, but nowhere I can find a solution. In the following html  code markers of `<li>` are  at the bottom of `<inframe>` How to do to be in the middle or at the top `<inframe>` ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <ul style=" list-style-position: inside;">
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the CSS property `vertical-align:middle;` to the iframe. This will make the bullet go to the middle of the list.

```css
iframe{
  vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <ul style=" list-style-position: inside;">
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
      <li> <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">  </iframe> </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```